# BigQuery flattens result when selecting into table with GROUP BY even with "noflatten_results" flag on

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with duplicate records. I want to remove them. I've created a column called "hash_code" which is just a sha1 hash of all the columns. Duplicate rows will have the same hash code. Everything is fine except when I tried to create a new table with a query containing GROUP BY. My table has RECORD data type, but the new table created flattens it even when I had specified it to not flatten. Seems like GROUP BY and the "-noflatten_results" flag doesn't place nice.

Here's an example command line I ran:

```
bq query --allow_large_results --destination_table mydataset.my_events --noflatten_results --replace 
"select hash_code, min(event) as event, min(properties.adgroup_name) as properties.adgroup_name, 
min(properties.adid) as properties.adid, min(properties.app_id) as properties.app_id,  
min(properties.campaign_name) as properties.campaign_name from mydataset.my_orig_events group each 
by hash_code "
```

In the above example, properties is a RECORD data type with nested fields. The resulting table doesn't have properties as RECORD data type. Instead it translated properties.adgroup_name to properties_adgroup_name, etc.

Any way to force BigQuery to treat the result set as RECORD and not flatten in GROUP BY?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a few known cases where query results can be flattened despite requesting unflattened results.

1. Queries containing a `GROUP BY` clause
2. Queries containing an `ORDER BY` clause
3. Selecting a nested field with a flat alias (e.g. `SELECT record.record.field AS flat_field`).  Note that this only flattens the specific field with the alias applied, and only flattens the field if it and its parent records are non-repeated.

The BigQuery query engine always flattens query results in these cases.  As far as I know, there is no workaround for this behavior, other than removing these clauses or aliases from the query.

Comment: Hm, I get flattened result even with simple 'SELECT * FROM [mytable]' query. No grouping, no aliases used. I'm confused.

Comment: Are you setting flatten_results to false?  The default behavior of BigQuery is to flatten query results.  If you're setting flatten_results to false and getting flattened output, reply with a job ID and I can investigate further.

Comment: I see it defined in `JobConfigurationQuery#setFlattenResults`, however can't find a way to call this method anywhere from in Java API. Any idea? Also, the docs says we must set `allowLargeResults = true`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the Java API, but this issue seems more suited to a separate question than a comment thread. I suggest posting a question on the google-bigquery tag, so someone more knowledgeable about the Java API might be able to help.