# Adding an ORDER BY statement to a query without flattening results leads to "Cannot query the cross product of repeated fields"

Tags: google-bigquery

```
Query: 
    "SELECT * FROM [table] ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"
    AllowLargeResults = true
    FlattenResults = false

table schema:
    [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "NULLABLE"
        },
        {
            "name": "repeated_field_1",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "REPEATED"
        },
        {
            "name": "repeated_field_2",
            "type": "STRING",
            "mode": "REPEATED"
        }
    ]
```

The query "SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 10" works just fine. I get this error when I add an order by clause, even though the order by does not mention either repeated field.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause causes BigQuery to automatically flatten the output of a query, causing your query to attempt to generate a cross product of repeated_field_1 and repeated_field_2.

If you don't care about preserving the repeatedness of the fields, you could explicitly `FLATTEN` both of them, which will cause your query to generate the cross product that the original query is complaining about.

```
SELECT *
FROM FLATTEN(FLATTEN([table], repeated_field_1), repeated_field_2)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Other than that, I don't have a good workaround for your query to both `ORDER BY` and also output repeated fields.

See also: [BigQuery flattens result when selecting into table with GROUP BY even with “noflatten_results” flag on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271139/bigquery-flattens-result-when-selecting-into-table-with-group-by-even-with-nofl/26394211#26394211)